# one-by-one matrix assignment MATLAB

Tags: matlab, min, assign

I need to find the minimum values in each column of matrix "A", and then replace those min values with the values in last row of matrix "B" (which has same number of columns). Like I have these:

```
>> A = randi(10,10,5)
A =
       3     5     9     5     8
       7     6     4    10     2
       8     4     1     7     4
       4     7     2     8     2
       7     5     8     7     5
       3     7    10    10     1
       5     7     8     5     7
       8     3     8     2     3
       6    10     2     1    10
       3     7     6     7     2
>> B = randi(100,3,5)
B =
      10    34    66    18    62
      99    95    49    54    81
      52     1    52     9    95
>> [M,I] = min(A)
    M =
         3     3     1     1     1
    I =
         1     8     3     9     6
```

And I want to replace the values of "M" with "B(end,:), so that:

```
A(1,1) = B(end,1);
A(8,2) = B(end,2);
A(3,3) = B(end,3);
A(9,4) = B(end,4);
A(6,5) = B(end,5);
```

I try `"A(I) = B(end,:)"` and `"A(I(1,:)) = B(end,:)"` but they do not work! Any ideas how I could do that? My real matrices are huge (1200x100000) so no way to do it by hand!

Comment: `A(sub2ind(size(A),I,1:size(A,2))) = B(end,:)` will work although there may be a better way

Comment: Don't work how exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this to replace **the first min value**:

```
A = [  3     5     9     5     8;
       7     6     4    10     2;
       8     4     1     7     4;
       4     7     2     8     2;
       7     5     8     7     5;
       3     7    10    10     1;
       5     7     8     5     7;
       8     3     8     2     3;
       6    10     2     1    10;
       3     7     6     7     2];
B =[  10    34    66    18    62;
      99    95    49    54    81;
      52     1    52     9    95];

[M,I] = min(A)
A(sub2ind(size(A),I,1:size(A,2)))=B(end,:)
```

the output will be:

```
A =

    52     5     9     5     8
     7     6     4    10     2
     8     4    52     7     4
     4     7     2     8     2
     7     5     8     7     5
     3     7    10    10    95
     5     7     8     5     7
     8     1     8     2     3
     6    10     2     9    10
     3     7     6     7     2
```

However, when you have to replace **all of the min values**, use the code below instead

```
A = [  3     5     9     5     8;
       7     6     4    10     2;
       8     4     1     7     4;
       4     7     2     8     2;
       7     5     8     7     5;
       3     7    10    10     1;
       5     7     8     5     7;
       8     3     8     2     3;
       6    10     2     1    10;
       3     7     6     7     2];
B =[  10    34    66    18    62;
      99    95    49    54    81;
      52     1    52     9    95];

M = min(A);    
for i=1:size(A,2)
  A(find(A(:,i) == M(i)),i)=B(end,i);
end;
A
```

the output is:

```
A =

    52     5     9     5     8
     7     6     4    10     2
     8     4    52     7     4
     4     7     2     8     2
     7     5     8     7     5
    52     7    10    10    95
     5     7     8     5     7
     8     1     8     2     3
     6    10     2     9    10
    52     7     6     7     2
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! @Hunter

Comment: Glad that I could help,  @Antonio

Answer (score 2):

You can acces you matrix by a single index, which looks like this:

```
Indeces =
          1  6 11 16 
          2  7 12 17 
          3  8 13 18 
          4  9 14 19 
          5 10 15 20
```

Since you get the indeces for each individual column, you just need to increase it by the column number times the height of the matrix.
This should yield the correct result:

```
A( I + (0 : size(A,2)-1) * size(A,1) ) = B(end,:)
```

Comment: Good insight. The `sub2ind` function does this computation for you.